# Django - how do you turn an InMemoryUploadedFile into an ImageField's FieldFile?

Tags: django, image, django-models, upload

I've been trying `help(django.db.models.ImageField)` and `dir(django.db.models.ImageField)`, looking for how you might create a `ImageField` object from an image that is uploaded.

`request.FILES` has the images as `InMemoryUploadedFile`, but I'm trying to save a model that contains an `ImageField`, so how do I turn the `InMemoryUploadedFile` into the `ImageField`?

How do you go about finding this type of thing out?  I suspect that the two classes have an inheritance relationship, but I'd have to do lots of `dir()` -ing to find out if I were to look.

Answer (score 26):

You need to save the `InMemoryUploadedFile` to the `ImageField` rather than 'turning' it into an `ImageField`:

```
image = request.FILES['img']
foo.imagefield.save(image.name, image)
```

where *foo* is the model instance, and *imagefield* is the `ImageField`.

Alternatively, if you are pulling the image out of a form:

```
image = form.cleaned_data.get('img')
foo.imagefield.save(image.name, image)
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. Yo can use the file content as you wish without saving it in a model instance. Inspect the file attribute

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. You saved my time.

Comment: What if the form is not binded to a model? Actually it expects a File, not an InMemoryUploadedFile, and the form is not validated.

Answer (score 3):

You trying to do it in ModelForm?

This is how i did for file field

```
class UploadSongForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mp3File

    def save(self):
        content_type = self.cleaned_data['file'].content_type
        filename = gen_md5() + ".mp3"
        self.cleaned_data['file'] = SimpleUploadedFile(filename, self.cleaned_data['file'].read(), content_type)
        return super(UploadSongForm, self).save()
```

You can take it as example and look in source what InMemoryUploadedFile class needs in initialization parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into your example closer tomorrow.  I'm bypassing the forms process, as I'm trying to save users from uploading images twice, so can't do the cleaned_data thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a form with a file upload field by using form instances, here is the view:

```
def form_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FooForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render_to_response('result.html')
        return render_to_response('form.html', {
            'form': form;
            'error_messages': form.errors;
        }
    form = FooForm()
    return render_to_response('form.html', {
        'form': form;
    }
```

*form.save()* saves the uploaded file along with all the other fields as you included *request.FILES* argument in it's constructor. In your models you have to define *FooForm* subclass of *ModelForm* class like this:

```
class FooForm(ModleForm):
    Meta:
        model = Foo
```

...where Foo is the subclass of *Model*, that describes the data you want to store persistently.